# How to change valid HTML tags that get rendered in ng-bind-html?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a text editor (textAngular) that I've modified to limit the number of valid HTML tags I can generate using that tool.  Now, I want to only support a limited number of HTML elements (h3, h4, h5, h6, ol, ul) to produce a news story but I want to disable some of the valid HTML rendered by ng-bind-html.  Namely, I want to remove ,  tags as a valid tags because they could have disastrous results for this user generated content.

Is it possible to remove  and  tags as something rendered by ng-bind-html?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, it isn't possible to config the valid HTML tags.

The `ng-bind-html` use the `$sanitize` service to strip invalid tags/attributes, and you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.22/src/ngSanitize/sanitize.js#L176) that all the configurations are private.

```
// Safe Block Elements - HTML5
var blockElements = angular.extend({}, optionalEndTagBlockElements, makeMap("address,article," +
        "aside,blockquote,caption,center,del,dir,div,dl,figure,figcaption,footer,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5," +
        "h6,header,hgroup,hr,ins,map,menu,nav,ol,pre,script,section,table,ul"));

// Inline Elements - HTML5
var inlineElements = angular.extend({}, optionalEndTagInlineElements, makeMap("a,abbr,acronym,b," +
        "bdi,bdo,big,br,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,i,img,ins,kbd,label,map,mark,q,ruby,rp,rt,s," +
        "samp,small,span,strike,strong,sub,sup,time,tt,u,var"));
```

If you really want it, one way you could do is to copy the `angular-sanitize.js` and modify the valid HTML tags configuration directly.

Please note that if you do it that way, all the `ng-bind-html` in your entire application will be also affected. If that is undesired, you have to write your own custom directive and inject/use your modified version of `$sanitize` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you're into modifying textAngular already, you could modify something around the taCustomRenderers Section of the code and use `ta-bind` instead of `ng-bind-html`. They do nearly the same thing except `ta-bind` runs all the extra renderers.

Custom Renderers Code: [textAngularSetup](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/blob/master/src/textAngularSetup.js#L61-L78), [textAngular](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/blob/master/src/textAngular.js#L1296-L1320) - probably in this one you can do your stripping out of unwanted code.